# Capitalize title in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to capitalize the title but it isn't seem to be working. I manage to get the other words using css "capitalize" but can't get my head around to make it work with AngularJS title.

This is the angularJS code:

```
    <title ng-bind="title"></title>
```

This is the html output:

```
    <title ng-bind="title" class="ng-binding">james byrne</title>
```

I want to capitalize both J as well as B.

Comment: you could write your own filter to capitalize. e.g. use something like this: `ng-bind='title | capitalize'` see -> http://codepen.io/WinterJoey/pen/sfFaK

Comment: There is not a native Angular capitalize function, but as Raphael said, you can create your own filter. I ran across an example you may appreciate: http://codepen.io/WinterJoey/pen/sfFaK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use custom filter

```
<title  ng-bind="(title| makeCaps)"></title>


app.filter('makeCaps',function(){

  return function(input){

   var capsInput = input.split(' '),
       newInput = [];

   angular.forEach(capsInput,function(val,index){
    newInput.push(val.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+val.substr(1));   
  });
    return newInput.join(' ');
  }

});
```

Comment: I'm not using {{title}} as this creates a problem while loading. I'm not sure how to go about this in my code :(

Answer (score 3):

I hope it helps :)

```
 <title ng-bind="title" class="ng-binding" style="text-transform:capitalize">james byrne</title>

<span data-ng-bind="caps" style="text-transform:capitalize">james bond</span>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="caps"/>
```

[image]

Comment: This didn't work. It was the first thing that came to my mind too.

Comment: For some reason, it didn't work for my title tag. It works only for other html content. Anyways, it got it working using shushanth's solution.

Comment: I tested the same in chrome and IE works fine. anyways you got it working  thats what matters :)

Comment: i'm talking about <title>Welcome</title> in <head> section. Not in body. Yes, that's what matters. Thank You :)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by creating by creating a `capitalize` filter and then use `ng-bind` along with the text to be filtered.

**[Demo Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/D9yEVC94rGwiy5xHlUy3?p=preview)**

**[Demo Page](http://run.plnkr.co/kRkkzgHZt4An9dD3/)**

**HTML**

```
<title ng-bind="title | capitalize"></title>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.title = 'james byrne';
  })

  .filter('capitalize', function() {
    return function(string) {
      return string.split(' ').map(function(string) {
        string = string.trim();
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.substr(1).toLowerCase();
      }).join(' ');
    };
  });
```

Comment: @User3362364 - I suggest you and go with Ryeballar answer.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own custom filter while in filter you can use regex to capitalize each letter as :

```
var tempArray = $scope.title.match(/ [a-z]/);
for(i = 0, i<tempArray.length, i++)
  {
    tempArray[i] = tempArray[i].slice(1);
    $scope.title.replace(/ [a-z]/, tempArray[i].toUpperCase());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple javaScript to perform this ..

```
document.title = document.title.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: capitalize is not uppercase, and angular have builtin filter for that called "uppercase"